# How to show information box in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento

I am trying to use the following code to display an information box:

```
Mage::getSingleton(’core/session’)->addError('***');
```

This is showing an error message.

However, I want an information box to be displayed and not an error message.

Comment: Is your question regarding to Enable Template/Block ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to display different messages.

To display a **Notice message** box:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Notice message');
```

To display a **Success message** box:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success message');
```

To display an **Error message** box:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Error message');
```

To display a **Warning message** box (admin only):

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addWarning('Warning message');
```